# Camera doesn't move right in Dota

Tags: display-resolution, steam, ubuntu-gnome

My screen resolution is 1360x768. In Linux the setting 1366x768 is used. When I tried to move camera to the right in the game it doesn't move as well as in other directions.

I tried to add 1360x768 as a screen resolution in xrand but it's already in there, however I can't choose it. What might be issue for this?

Using Ubuntu 22.04.1 Gnome 42.4

Comment: How is turning a camera to the right and screen resolution related?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'd say directly, but idk. Probably it's because of the left dock panel. When I set the dock to down, a camera can move right, but not able to move down. Although, when I change resolution to 1200 in Linux or Dota settings, camera works properly as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a library libxcvt0_0.1.2 fixes the problem.